# Timer event does not fire until WaitOne times out

Tags: multithreading, timer, autoresetevent

I have a timer that fires periodically to check for new data. Occasionally, I need the timer to fire immediately and I need to wait for timer handler to do its thing before continuing. I tried having the handler set an AutoResetEvent that my main thread would then wait on but this did not work. The timer would not fire until after my call to WaitOne timed out. I have tried using System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer with the same results. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are semaphores or locks not useful in this case?

Comment: Just don't wait for the timer to tick, call the tick event handler method directly.

Comment: I reconstructed my code line-by-line starting from a Microsoft example that did work. It turns out that my handler was raising an event whose handler was checking for the InvokeRequired attribute of a control and then doing a synchronous Invoke of a method to update the control. Since the thread that created the control was now waiting for my original handler to signal it was done updating its data, I had a deadlock situation. I fixed this issue by switching to a BeginInvoke.